# Using Autolayout to make automatic grow UILabel and push object below

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, xib

I am sorry but this is getting complicated for me. I am 20% Autolayout user (poor). I need the text "my name is gerard and can't understand autolayout..." to show completely and push the objects below when grow. 1st line of the label must be aligned with the right label that says "Mensaje".

[image]

Comment: Show what constraints you've added so far

Comment: @Wain thank you for your quick reply. There are 4 constraints: http://imgur.com/a/xo2QZ I think the 3rd one which is trailing the view below (Notas) has to do with this, but I am not sure.

Comment: @tomasfn you should either set [`preferredMaxLayoutWidth`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth) value or some width constraint for your label if you want it to grow vertically. And also make sure `numberOfLines` is set to `0`.

Comment: @Wain I am sorry, "Notas" actually is the view where the Label and the objects above are placed in.

Comment: @ozgur thank you, numberOfLines is set to 0 already. Now I added the width constraint but I am not sure how to handle it: http://imgur.com/RfaKj0j in the preview image it shows 2 lines of the label

Comment: @ozgur sorry to be annoying, would love some more help!

Comment: @tomasfn you should align two labels horizontally on the top with another constraint.

Comment: if your project is not so private, maybe you can upload it to your github repo so we can play around with it to help you figure out the problem.

Comment: @ozgur Do you mean this? https://i.imgur.com/AYrcc30.png, Sorry but can't upload the entire project this time, I hate that. These are all the constraints for the label imgur.com/a/xo2QZ. Is important to say that Notas is a highlighted view and below the both red and green buttons are part of other view.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the numberOfLines of the UILabel is set to 0. Let the top of the label be aligned with the Mensajes top. Let label.bottom = entregar.top - 5 or something like that. Also let label.right = superview.right

Comment: I can't follow, sorry... could you be more descriptive?